# How do I build Watir tests for websites?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

There is a [repository of tests](https://github.com/mozilla/Addon-Tests) for the Mozilla addons site, although it's written using Selenium. I'd like to know if there are any real-world examples available for Watir, so I can see how the framework is implemented by professionals?

This is a more general question about how one goes about building a suite of tests for a website in Watir. On a superficial level, one can write a bunch of seperate .rb files with crude error reporting and fire them all off; but I'd like to know more about writing actual classes and proper test structures that raise issues and return reports. How is this done? Are there any books on this? Tutorials?

Comment: On your project is a continuous integration (ci) system used?  The one we use here is Hudson, which takes reports generated by the ci-reporter gem and magics them up into readable reports that let you see what's passed and failed pretty easily.  I'm not sure on the specifics as the setup was handled by someone much more in the know about CI stuff than me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The watir Wiki  has a selection of tutorials, examples etc as well.

- [Start Here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Start+Here)
- [Learning More](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Learning+More)
- [Wiki homepage](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Project+Home)

Those are however fairly basic and don't get into the 'how to organize things' level.

In that case there are a number of [frameworks](http://watir.com/frameworks/) in various states of development.  The most active ones are I think are perhaps Taza, and QA Robusta.  Each of them approaches things a little differently.  QA Robusta is wrapped a bit around Minitest (if I understand things right) and provides it's own reporting.  I'm still learning about Taza so can't really comment on it much.  I also recall hearing about a '[WatirSpash](https://github.com/jarmo/WatirSplash)' gem/framework that was discussed in a recent [watir podcast](http://watirpodcast.com/) which is designed to help watir use along with RSpec (and I might presume Cucumber)

If you are a BDD/Spec-by-example sort, then you may want to use either (or both) RSpec or Cucumber perhaps in combination with the WatirSpash gem as a way to organize and describe you tests, and then implement the actual test code via Watir, In that case you would likely be using the HTML based reports that can be generated by RSpec/Cucumber instead of rolling your own or depending on a watir framework for the reporting.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [WatirMelonCucumber](http://watirmelon.com/2011/01/21/my-simple-cucumber-watir-page-object-pattern-framework/) - a set of watir-webdriver tests against google and bing, and also [EtsyWatirWebDriver](http://watirmelon.com/2011/04/23/watir-webdriver-etsy/) - a set of watir-webdriver tests against Etsy.com

Answer (score 2):

More Watir frameworks:

https://github.com/jarmo/WatirSplash
https://cyberconnect.biz/opensource/qa_robusta.html

Not in active development:

https://github.com/scudco/taza
https://github.com/bret/watircraft

Answer (score 1):

QA Robusta most likely will not have too many new features added but will be supported.  Instead you may want to check out [whirlwind](https://github.com/ccyphers/whirlwind).  Whirlwind uses similar concepts as other frameworks such as qa_robusta and taza, but is lighter weight and tailored around cucumber/rspec.  See the [walk through](https://github.com/ccyphers/whirlwind/wiki/Implementing-A-Site---Google-Search-Walkthrough) for a google search example.